# REST API/any other solution required: Deploy artifact on app server from Artifactory through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am DevOps beginner, experimenting over the AWS server to learn.

I have created a job in Jenkins which run whenever any new push comes to my GITHUB, Maven build the code from GITHUB and archive the WAR file in Artifactory.

I want to take next step now in which, the build artifact would be taken from Artifacotry and need to deploy on my App server.

I look for solution and could not find any good explanation on this.

Can anyone share the steps/solution to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is your App server triggered? Is it running on the same server as jenkins?

Comment: No it would be deployed on different server (Jenkins Node).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve this is by creating an additional job Jenkins, which is responsible for downloading the artifacts of a specific build from Artifactory and deploying them to your Application Server. I recommend using the Pipeline DSL for Artifactory or a Free-Style job with the Generic Artifactory Integration, because both include a convenient JSON File Spec definition, which allows you to filter which artifacts you want to download, based on a specific build or even the latest build published.
Once the job downloaded the artifacts to the job's workspace, it needs to copy them to your Application Server. There are many ways to do that. You can use a deployment tool like Ansible to push (copy) the artifacts from job workspace to your servers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new jenkins job say `job1_deployApp` to deploy your App server. Configure this job as downstream job of the other job from where you want to copy the build artifacts say `job2_build`.

Configure `archive artifacts` in `job2_build` to archive the needed build artifacts. So once this job is over it will trigger `job1_deployApp`.

Configure `job1_deployApp` to `copy artifacts` from `job2_build`. It will copy all the artifacts which were archived in `job2_build. Hence you will get the required artifacts to deploy your App server.

Comment: Thanks Rajeesh for answer!
As i already setup my job to build and save the artifact on artifactory now i need to do the following-
1) Add deployment server as node/slave in Jenkins
2) Create a job to copy artifact from Artifacotry and deploy it on slave server. 

Here i am looking the steps to do the point 2. Hope this would clarify more.